# Why is my UITableView getting its images messed up?

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, image, sdk

I'm trying to get my UITableView to show cells with images placed on them (contained in a UIImageView overlaid). I'm wondering why when scrolling up and down, the images look like they're overlaid on top of one another.

What can I do in this case for the sake of memory management as well as to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you reuse and setup your cells properly... hard to say anything specific without seeing the code

Comment: Probably not releasing the NSImage or adding or adding UIImageView each time the row is displayed.

Comment: remove the image .... you are probably giving away your, or even worse, your client's idea for an amazing app!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that when you're dequeuing a reusable cell that you *remove* whatever image view was in the cell before you add the one for the current index path.

Alternatively, you can change the image property of the UIImageView.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You're using the default "cell" reuse ID for everything and not clearing out the previous contents. (Pass `nil` for the ID to verify that this is the problem, then fix it for real for good perf)